# ZIP File looses Managed Metadata values when editing

Tags: 2013, document-library, managed-metadata, document

A user has created a ZIP file with meeting protocols and has tagged the zip file with our provided managed metadata (term store). Every time when he's editing the ZIP file (check out - add files) he looses all the values in the managed metadata columns. 
Has anybody the same issue and a solution for this? 
Regards Michael